# Separating a string into substrings, converting them to ints, and assigning them to an instance variable

Tags: java, string, substring

I have this program that requests the user to enter a time in the format of XX:XX, where X is a digit. It accepts this as a string. I'm trying to figure out how I can take this string, separate the first 2 digits into a substring, convert them to integers, and assign them to the "hours" instance variable. Then to do the same for the following 2 digits as "minutes". But how can I separate a single string with specific index values. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String time = "XX:XX";

int hours = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2));
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3,5));
```

Comment: int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3,2)); will throw an exception.  See Noob's answer for the correct parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Best way is to use `String.split()` to separate at the colon:

```
String myString = "01:45";
String[] parts = myString.split(":");
//parts[0] = "01"
//parts[1] = "45"
```

Then you can access the parts individually:

```
int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int part2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
//part1 = 1
//part2 = 45
```

Comment: This method would work best because it doesn't depend on the hours value having exactly 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. First you take the substring of both the hour and minute, then use parseInt to convert the string to an integer.

```
    String time = "12:30";
    String hour = time.substring (0, 2);
    String minute = time.substring (3, 5);

    int hourNum = Integer.parseInt(hour);
    int minNum = Integer.parseInt(minute);

    System.out.print (hourNum + ":" + minNum);
```